# find out when procedure/function was changed for specific schema in postger

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-catalog

I have DB with the multiple schemas, in one of the schemas someone changed the function, I am trying to find when it happens for that i am using the next query

```
select proname,oid, xmin,
'|||||||||', 
* 
from pg_catalog.pg_proc 
where proname = 'FUNCT_NAME'
order by xmin::text::int 
desc;
```

now I am facing the issue, I can't specify the schema name and cannot find how to convert **xmin** to the date-time.
I was trying to use `pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin)`  but it was disabled so I can get any info is there a way to check the date time when it was changed?

Comment: Have you set [track_commit_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP) and restarted the server? If was not enabled before it will only return a value for transactions started after it was set. You use `pronamespace` to specify the schema name as in: `... pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no I didn't set it :(, and it was off that's why I am trying to find out if there is another way to do it?

Comment: There is not another way.